# Angular 2 : while loading page in internet explorer 11 gives error - SCRIPT5009: 'System' is undefined

Tags: node.js, angular

I have developed single page application using Angular 2, node , express. It is running fine on chrome and firefox. but same is now working on IE 11. Used following code 
Giving error to **System** in script tag. ***SCRIPT5009: 'System' is undefined***

```
<html class="ng-scope">

  <head>
    <base href="/"/>
    <title>Test application</title>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="libs/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>


   <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link  href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">




    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/bootstrap')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>

<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <!-- End wrapper-->

    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>    


  </body>

</html>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution using following link.
I have added two javascript reference **es6-shim.min.js** and **shims_for_IE.js**

```
<script src="libs/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7144

**Note** : *In this reference libs = node_modules*

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.1/es6-shim.js"></script>
```

as first script library

Comment: Added  script library but still giving same error
Added at top first reference before polyfills.js

Comment: try adding system and its pollyfill before angular after es6-shim

Comment: I have tried combination as you suggested but still it is giving me error